# google API assistant SDK

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id  --device-id

I use this code to try and get the project running and I get this error:
ERROR:root:Option --device-model-id required when registering a device instance.

I have tried lots of different versions of the device ID and I feel that I may just not understand what it is.

Comment: Provide more information about your problem.

Comment: Update the whole process through again and I am still getting the same errors. Is there a code I could run to get the ID? such as googlesamples-assistant-devicetool